Creating Mutli Colored Font
I am playing around with the igo package to create notes on the game of Go. Under the hood, it seems like the igo package computes a font for all of the symbols on the board, and simply prints a block of text. Within the package there are a bunch of .mf files, corresponding with categories of pieces, that when compiled generate .600pk and .tfm files.
The white pieces don't look great in this package, and I want to play around with having true white pieces on a off white page color, but when I attempt this the pieces become off white as well. From what I have seen, it looks like .mf font files only allow monochromatic characters, and the white parts of the white pieces are actually just transparent.
Is it possible, to use MetaPost to generate .tfm and .600pk font files that have multi colored symbols? This would allow me to fill in the centers of the white pieces with true white. If not, is there anything else I should consider? My backup plan is rewrite everything with tikz.

Welcome! Well, Metapost can certainly do colour. But I think you really want to ask about Metafont? As far as I know, you can't have multi-coloured glyphs without moving to opentype/truetype fonts. Neither mf nor type1 support this (and I'm not certain about truetype). But if you are planning to redo everything in TikZ, then you're presumably not then thinking of producing fonts. At that point, Metapost should be considered because the transition from mf to mp will be smoother than to TikZ. Support for the same curves etc. Colour's no problem in Metapost.

Moreover, metapost has the concept of pens/brushes, which aligns with mf. TikZ doesn't have any of that.

Reading through metapost documentation, it looks like "withcolor white" is the pen modifier I am looking for. Do you have a CLI and some documentation you can point me to that will turn a metapost file into a .tfm and a .600pk output?

No. That's not possible. You can't generate fonts from multicolour metapost. (At least, not mf/pk.) My point was that rather than redrawing stuff in TikZ, you would probably find it easier to transition it to Metapost, since it is very like an extended form of Metafont. It produces postscript figures, basically - diagrams, etc. It can do certain things easily which TikZ can't or can't do at all and some of those are fundamental to Metafont, as I understand it. (Note I've not used metafont, but only metapost, but they're both derived from the same base.)

Ah I understand. I will consider that. Thank you

Type 3 PostScript fonts would be an option here. They're limited to a fairly small subset of PostScript, but it includes everything that MetaPost outputs, and it definitely allows colour. Every PDF viewer that I've tested can display Type 3 fonts, but essentially nothing supports embedding arbitrary Type 3 font files. For something wildly experimental and undocumented, you can try https://github.com/gucci-on-fleek/unnamed-emoji. The backend uses pure MetaPost, so it shouldn't be too hard to hack in a direct MetaPost reader.

Chapter 16 in the luametafun manual might be interesting to look into.
